# Combining two interpolating functions via Piecewise or If is very slow

Tags: interpolation, piecewise

For a given set of parameters $(i,l,m)$ I have a function which has been evaluated on a grid $x \in (-2,2)$. Since this function is not smooth (only continuous) at the "interface" $x=0$, I am interpolating separately the values defined for $x<0$ and $x>0$. I then combine them into a single function using `Piecewise` or `If`.

```
xmin = -2; xInterface = 0; xmax = 2;
xgrid =  Range[xmin, xmax, 1/100];

Clear[myPolyLeft,myPolyRight,leftInterpol, rightInterpol, fullInterpol]    
Monitor[Do[
(* set up the table left and right of the interface *)
interfaceValue = RandomReal[{1, 10}];
myPolyLeft[x_] = RandomReal[{1, 3}] x^2 + RandomReal[{1, 10}] x + interfaceValue;
myPolyRight[x_] = RandomReal[{1, 3}] x^2 + RandomReal[{1, 10}] x + interfaceValue;
leftTable = Table[myPolyLeft[xmin + (xInterface - xmin) i/200], {i, 0, 200}];
rightTable = Table[myPolyRight[xInterface + (xmax - xInterface) i/200], {i, 0, 200}];

(* interpolate and stitch the solutions together *)
leftInterpol[i][l, m] = Interpolation[Transpose[{xgrid[[;; 201]], leftTable}]];
rightInterpol[i][l, m] = Interpolation[Transpose[{xgrid[[201 ;;]], rightTable}]];
fullInterpol[i][l, m][x_] =  If[x < xInterface, Evaluate[leftInterpol[i][l, m][x]], Evaluate[rightInterpol[i][l, m][x]]]
, {i, 1, 10}, {l, 2, 40}, {m, -l, l}]
, {i, l, m}]
```

What I am surpised to see is that evaluating `fullInterpol` on a grid takes about 1000x longer than evaluating the indvidual "left" and "right" interpolating functions:

```
(* Do using i:1-10,l:2-40 *)
Table[rightInterpol[10][3, 2][xInterface + i (xmax - xInterface)/100], {i, 0, 100}]; // AbsoluteTiming
Table[leftInterpol[10][3, 2][xmin + i (xInterface - xmin)/100], {i, 0, 100}]; // AbsoluteTiming
Table[fullInterpol[10][3, 2][xmin + i (xmax - xmin)/100], {i, 0, 100}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* Timing Output:0.000275,0.000258,0.312824 *)
```

Even more perplexing, as @DanielHuber pointed out, if I then set

```
fun[10][3, 2][x_] = fullInterpol[10][3, 2][x];
```

and do a timing test on `fun`:

```
Table[fun[10][3, 2][xmin + i (xmax - xmin)/100], {i, 0,  100}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* Timing Output: 0.000327 *)
```

Furthermore, the time to evaluate `fullInterpol` seems to be affected by the range of parameter $(i,l,m)$. For example, choosing to only apply the Do loop for i=10, the timings are then:

```
(* Do using i:10-10, l:2-40 *)    
Table[rightInterpol[10][3, 2][xInterface + i (xmax - xInterface)/100], {i, 0, 100}]; // AbsoluteTiming
Table[leftInterpol[10][3, 2][xmin + i (xInterface - xmin)/100], {i, 0, 100}]; // AbsoluteTiming
Table[fullInterpol[10][3, 2][xmin + i (xmax - xmin)/100], {i, 0, 100}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*Timing Output: 0.000277, 0.00026, 0.000985 *)
```

The evaluation of the two interpolating functions are unaffected as expected, but `fullInterpol` is now much faster. Something similar can be seen by reducing the range of $l$ instead.

What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps avoid `SubValues` and even `DownValues`.  The problem is set up for simple table look up, and with this approach, it is just as fast as evaluating the individual interpolating functions:

```
Clear[fullInterpol2]
Monitor[interpData = Table[
    {leftInterpol[i][l, m], rightInterpol[i][l, m]}, {i, 1, 10}, {l, 
     2, 40}, {m, -l, l}], {i, l, m}];
fullInterpol2[i_, l_, m_, x_] := 
  interpData[[i, l - 1, m + l + 1, 1 + UnitStep[x]]][x];

Table[rightInterpol[10][3, 2][
    xInterface + i (xmax - xInterface)/100], {i, 0, 
    100}]; // AbsoluteTiming
Table[leftInterpol[10][3, 2][xmin + i (xInterface - xmin)/100], {i, 0,
     100}]; // AbsoluteTiming
foo1 = Table[
    fullInterpol[10][3, 2][xmin + i (xmax - xmin)/100], {i, 0, 
     100}]; // AbsoluteTiming
foo2 = Table[
    fullInterpol2[10, 3, 2, xmin + i (xmax - xmin)/100], {i, 0, 
     100}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*
{0.000353, Null}
{0.000332, Null}
{0.135156, Null}
{0.000336, Null}
*)

(* Check *)
foo1 == foo2
(*  True  *)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug in the definition of fullInterpol. "If" has the attribute "HoldRest". This makes the subsequent evaluation symbolically. To se this, consider:

```
l = 3; m = 2;
fullInterpol[i][l, m][x_] = 
 If[x < xInterface, leftInterpol[i][l, m][x], 
  rightInterpol[i][l, m][x]]
```

this returns:

```
If[x < 0, leftInterpol[i][l, m][x], rightInterpol[i][l, m][x]]
```

l and m have no value.

To fix this, you must force evaluation like:

```
l = 3; m = 2;
fullInterpol[i][l, m][x_] = 
 If[x < xInterface, Evaluate[leftInterpol[i][l, m][x]], 
  Evaluate[rightInterpol[i][l, m][x]]]
```

This now returns:

```
If[x < 0, leftInterpol[i][3, 2][x], rightInterpol[i][3, 2][x]]
```

Comment: Hi Daniel. Thank you. I edited the question to fix this bug. I still obtain the same kind of timing tests though

Comment: If you set: `fun[x_] = fullInterpol[10][3, 2][x];` and do the timing on `fun`, then it is fast. I do not understand this. Maybe if you can simplify it it is worth a report to support@wolfram.com.

Comment: I updated the question. This is quite perpexing...